# Facebook fan page managing

Tags: facebook, account

Maybe is a little bit weird as a question but, I have a facebook account and with this account i manage a facebook fan page. Now i wanna hut my personal account down, but is there a way to continue managing my fan page even with my personal account closed account?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question. For Facebook end user support, please consult their Help section.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't seem to be possible from the threads I came across that.
Your best bet is making someone else the admin or creating a fake account and making it the admin of the page before shutting down your account.